# Does Resharper have a "search everywhere"?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellij-idea, resharper

I normally use WebStorm (spin-off of IntelliJ IDEA), which has a wonderful "search everywhere" feature.  I use this for finding files, types, and especially commands.

I'm just starting to use Resharper in Visual Studio 2012, and it's sometimes hard to find the commands I'm looking for.  I was hoping to find a "search everywhere" feature, but I looked through all the Resharper menu items, and couldn't find any.

Is there any sort of "search everywhere" for Resharper?  I'm hoping to find an easy way to search through the list of commands (like refactorings, navigations, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The feature is integrated with the "Context Actions" popup; press `Alt-Enter` and start typing the name of any action you need.

[image: Enter Action Name Screenshot]
[image: Camel Case Supported Screenshot]

Comment: Wow, you're right!  This is exactly what I was looking for!  
I'm very surprised, because it's absolutely not intuitive that you can just "start typing" into that list.  It's also not intuitive that it can only be activated from within the Text Editor.